# Wicket - Create new folder per session

Tags: java, session, wicket, dir

I am using apache wicket 1.5 and when a new session is initialized I want to create a new temp folder:

**Example:**

Session_1_connect -> create_temp_1

Session_1_disconnect -> delete_temp_1

**A new user logs in:**

Session_2_connect -> create_temp_2

Session_2_disconnect -> delete_temp_2

I know how to make dirs in java, thats not a problem. Its just how to configure it in wicket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this even without Wicket by simply implemeting the functionality in `sessionCreated()` and `sessionDestroyed()` in your own [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) and then adding it like this to your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.your.package.YourSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of the `Session` seems a logical place.. just make sure you delete the folder after a while..